# React native - The development server returned respose error code:404

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to create simple react-native project,
Also I read about the RR- reload the js code without run it again after changes.
My problem is that when I change the code in index.android.js file I need to run:

```
1. `react-native run-android`
2. `curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"`
3. `react-native run-android again.`
```

If I run only `react-native run-android` the code isn't update!
Also I tried to stash the device and click on `reload` option without run `react-native run-android` command, but it's not reloading I got error like this:The development server returned respose error code:404,

I looked for some solution about this error, and find out that I need to configure the Dev Settings "debug server host & port for device" to my local ip address,
I treid to change it to : 10.0.0.3 -> my local Ip address, but still get errors,
Also changed it to :10.0.0.3:8080-> add the port, but nothing... the errors still appears,

In the error explantion I saw that I can try to run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` command, but nothing... its not resolve the errors,

Is someone has any idea how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If anyone still looking for a solution this might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773509/the-development-server-returned-respose-error-code404-react-native

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

> Looks like you switched on another app and came back again on previous one. Anyway to solve this issue just kill all existing process those are on port 8081 and run code again:
>
> For Linux/Ubuntu system you can do this :

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8018)
```

> After this run android app again

```
react-native run-android
```