# The development server returned response error code:404 react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run react native app like this in cmd

```
cd C:\Users\User\Desktop\js

react-native run-android
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this after upgrading from react-native v.47 to latest.

Before, my project was using two index files, `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js`. After [this update](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.49.0)  only one file entry point is required, `index.js`. Move your index logic into a single `index.js` file that is at the same level and try again. This solved the error for me.

Comment: Actually,it leads to another exception "application has not been registered",but I think you solved this part,thx :))

Comment: After above change also, it not opening

Answer (score 9):

If you still have same issue just kill all existing processes that are on port 8081 and run code again.

For Linux/Ubuntu systems you can do this:

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8081)
```

After this run Android app again:

```
react-native run-android
```

Original question was 
[React native - The development server returned respose error code:404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651224/react-native-the-development-server-returned-respose-error-code404/52512223#52512223)

Answer (score 0):

you need to setup ip address of react native server with port number 8081

example 192.168.1.2:8081