# react-native android error: The development server returned response error code:404

Tags: react-native

When I run `react-native run-android` I get this error. Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The development server returned respose error code:404 react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773509/the-development-server-returned-respose-error-code404-react-native)

Comment: is your development server running? Usually a node js server bundling and serving your source code

Comment: same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773509/the-development-server-returned-respose-error-code404-react-native